Why do constructivists accept the countable choice?
There are variants of constructive mathematics. Many of them (e.g. Bishop's constructive mathematics) seem to accept the axiom of countable choice.
I agree that the axiom of choice is not constructive, but I don't see why constructivists accept the countable choice.
What is the philosophical difference?

Countable choice does not imply excluded middle.

Only some constructivists do so (albeit many), and largely because there is a popular computational interpretation of constructive mathematics in terms realizability that derives countable choice. It is discussed in Bauer's paper and more briefly in his answer on MO. In a nutshell, one can construct the choice function when sets are represented computationally, as in Bishop's work.

I wish I could upvote this question twice.

Because (arbitrary) sets are a constructive problem; lists are not. See

edit: changed notation after I realised philosophy stackexchange does not render mathjax.
I have not done any formal logic, but from an analyst's perspective the difference between countable choice and uncountable choice is the well-ordering principle.
Suppose I have a countable set X. Then there is a bijection between X and the natural numbers. This bijection induces an order relation on X, and furthermore it means that any non-empty subset of X will have a smallest member. Suppose I have a countable number of non-empty sets A(k), for k = 1, 2, ..., composed of members of X (i.e. subsets of X). For each k I can choose the smallest x in A(k), and in this way I can systematically choose countably many things.
